# Bubble sort 2d array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Halo am trying to bubble sort a two dimensional array, help me debug.
Can sort without the array successfully but I need to sort using a  2d array which is not working out.

I need the by each row contents independently.
And incase you can do so using any other sorting algorithm it will also be of help

Thanks

```
//make a two dimensional array
function make2Darray(cols, rows){
var arr = new Array(cols);
 for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  arr[i] = new Array(rows);
}
return arr;
}
var unsortedData = new Array([40516, 51028, 64212, 66516, 82597],
[35606, 85929, 89405, 79392, 38572]);
//Generate array
var row =2, column =5, d=0;
var unsorted= make2Darray(column,row);

for(var r=0; r<row; ++r){
for(var c =0; c<column; ++c){

  unsorted[r][c] = unsortedData[d++];
}
}  

function bubbleSort(arrayData)
{
  document.write("<h3  class='text text-info'> Bubble Sort</h3>");
  document.write("At the end of each iteration highest element is already sorted. <br />");

  //Loop through to sort

  for ( var count1 =0; count1<5; count1++)// outer loop loops (number of elements- 1) times
  {
    for ( var counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
    {

    //Compare elements and swap incase
     if(arrayData[count1][counter] > arrayData[count1][counter+1])
     {
      //swap positions
      var temp = arrayData[count1][counter]; 
      arrayData[count1][counter] = arrayData[count1][counter+1];
      arrayData[count1][counter+1] = temp;


     }

    }

  }
  return arrayData;
}

//pass data to sort to bubble sort function
//Determine execution time
  var bs_start_time = performance.now();
  var bs_array = bubbleSort(unsorted);
  var c = bs_array.length;

//display sorted data
for(var i=0; i<row; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j<column; j++){
    document.write(bs_array[i][j] + ", ");

    }
    document.write("<br/>");
}
```

Comment: You should fix up your identation and stick to a consistent formatting

Answer (score 0):

I guess the outer loop must iterate to (count-1)=4 and the inner loop must iterate from count1+1 as You shall not swap the elements already sorted

```
for ( var count1 =0; count1<4; count1++)
  {
    for ( var counter = count1+1; counter < 5; counter++)
    {

    //Compare elements and swap incase
     if(arrayData[count1][counter] > arrayData[count1][counter+1])
     {
      //swap positions
      var temp = arrayData[count1][counter]; 
      arrayData[count1][counter] = arrayData[count1][counter+1];
      arrayData[count1][counter+1] = temp;


     }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ... thou I figured it out, added a third loop and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
//figured it out by adding a third loop
function bubbleSort(arrayData, r, c)
{
  document.write("<h3  class='text text-info'> Bubble Sort</h3>");
  document.write("At the end of each iteration highest element is already sorted. <br />"); 


  //Loop through to sort
  for ( var count =0; count<r; count++) // outer loop loops (number of elements- 1) times
  {
    for(var count2=c-1; count2>=0; count2--){
    for ( var counter = 0; counter <=count2; counter++)
    {

    //Compare elements and swap incase
     if(arrayData[count][counter] > arrayData[count][counter+1])
     {
      //swap positions
      var temp = arrayData[count][counter]; 
      arrayData[count][counter] = arrayData[count][counter+1];
      arrayData[count][counter+1] = temp;


     }

    }
  }

  }
  return arrayData;
}

//pass data to sort to bubble sort function
  var bs_array = bubbleSort(unsorted, row, column);
```